# .NET Maui CommunityToolkit.Maui Popup labels in Android positioning wrong

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-android

I recently did an App with .NET MAUI that had no errors, but last day I opened it to try and update a new compilation, I found out that all the labels in the Popups appear way more on the bottom than intended, cutting the label, and if I try to apply a padding to rise it up, it appears more up but cut the same way.

This, is only happening on Android, while on iOS everything is still good as it was before the update.

The only thing I changed during that update was some updated to NuGet Packages (including the CommunityToolkit), and I checked other Maui projects I have with popups, and having the same packages with the same versions, I don't have this problem.

I tried making a new project, copying the same code and the problem was still there.

The code of the label inside the popup is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct ="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             x:Class="Project.Popups.PopUp_Continue"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" x:Name="vStack" HeightRequest="205">

        <Label x:Name="Lbl_Message"
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="23"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"
               HeightRequest="120"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               Margin="10,10,10,0"
               />

        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="hStack" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="55">      
            <Button x:Name="Btn_No" Clicked="Btn_No_Clicked" BackgroundColor="IndianRed" Text="Cancelar" HeightRequest="55" FontSize="20" FontFamily="" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="Btn_Yes" Clicked="Btn_Yes_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Aceptar" HeightRequest="55" FontSize="20" FontFamily="" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mct:Popup>
```

And it displays like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HT1h-vP0_NqbcuQK71Ec0l_q1GSJPkn5/view?usp=sharing

Normally, it would display the label right in the center of the space between the button and the top of the Popup (since it doesn't work, I cannot show you an example)

Has somebody found and solved this problem?

Thanks.

Edits: After some investigation, I found out that the label seems to be vertically centering to the Popup height instead of centering to the height given to the label itself.

[image]

Manually setting the height of the label with Margins and Paddings, or following @H.A.H.'s comment, I'm getting this result:

[image]

@H.A.H.'s comment resulting code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct ="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             x:Class="Project.Popups.PopUp_Continue"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" x:Name="vStack" HeightRequest="205">
        <Grid HeightRequest="120">
            <Label x:Name="Lbl_Message"
                   Margin="0,50,0,50"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   FontSize="23"
                   FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"
                   />
        </Grid>
        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="hStack" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="55">      
            <Button x:Name="Btn_No" Clicked="Btn_No_Clicked" BackgroundColor="IndianRed" Text="Cancelar" HeightRequest="55" FontSize="20" FontFamily="" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="Btn_Yes" Clicked="Btn_Yes_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Aceptar" HeightRequest="55" FontSize="20" FontFamily="" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mct:Popup>
```

Comment: The XAML of the popup, picture what is happening, picture what you desire. (I have tested popups few days ago, new project, last toolkit version, everything worked fine on Android. Device and emulator tested.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some screenshots and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which will help others help you.

Comment: Did you try to use the [Display pop-ups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups)?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Yes, I did, but I have other Popups that can't be replaced by this ones, I just uploaded the simplest one so the code is smaller.

Comment: @H.A.H. I have been trying for days now, and even doing a new project with just a newly created Popup, in Android the labels center to the Popup, instead to the height given.

Comment: @Julian Yes, my bad. I hope I provided enough information with the last edits. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Ian Please add the picture directly to the post instead of linking to Google Drive. You can upload and embed images here.

Comment: @Julian I inserted a picture directly into the post now, it wouldn't allow me before

Comment: @Ian When I asked for the XAML. I mean the whole XAML. Not the Label in the XAML.

Comment: @H.A.H. I had all the XAML but I think the "`" ticks were placed wrong somehow and it didn't show everything. This popup is very simple, it doesn't really have anything else. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian Well done. And here are two ways to center your label in Android. TextAlignment does not work. (I am doing it by setting the same margin top and bottom, if I do not care for total size, and wrapping it in Grid, if I care for exact total size.) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove those lines:

```
Margin="10,10,10,0"
HeightRequest="120"
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
```

Then,
First way - wrap your control with Grid:

```
<Grid HeightRequest="120">
    <Label Text="Centered"
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
```

Second way - use margins top and bottom:

```
<Label Text="Centered"
           Margin="0,50,0,50"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
```

Edit to clarify a bit:

Using the first way, you will end up with label with specific height. (The height you specify in your Grid wrapper). Setting Horizontal and Vertical options here will make sure the text is centered.

Using the second way, the height of the field will be equal to Margin top + bottom + the height of the control itself. (That you should not specify) So the height being variable, you let it rest in the Stack itself, not within wrapper.

Paddings are not needed in both cases.

Comment: I'm getting the same error I was getting when "manually" setting the position more upwards with margins and paddings. I'll upload the result in a new edit of the main post.

Comment: @Ian show me your popup xaml, after the edits I suggested.

Comment: Added on the newest edit!

Comment: @Ian you EITHER wrap it in Grid, OR you set margins. Not both at the same time.

Comment: Yeah! That was it. It looks like with the last update of some package, apart from the margin + Grid issues, the TextAlignments are causing issues as well. With this method I'm being able to solve all the problems I was having with Popups (I had more complicated to explain ones). Thank you very much.